# Where is the best place to ask for opinion or guidance on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I am coming up to start my final year in September and I would like to be able to ask about what other people have done for their final year project and ideas etc, is there anyway within the Stack Overflow community where I can ask?

Comment: In the chat rooms.

Comment: What is actually wrong with this question? Why when the poster has gone to the effort to ask on meta stackoverflow 'where the best place to ask a question is' does he gets burned for that?

Comment: Derek, nothing is wrong with it. Some people here just have no life or love to throw around their point-hoarding power. Especially if they disagree with another's opinion. Why debate honestly when you can just shut them down? Crowd-sourced censorship! What if we don't want to use a chat room with so much back and forth interaction? I can get that at work! What if we just want a varied list of subjective opinions coming from experienced peers? No--we can't have the freedom to seek that here. *Asking for a few new perspectives from other techies destroys this site somehow.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Angelo points out [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266249/where-is-the-best-place-to-ask-for-opinion-or-guidance#comment64624_266249), the best place to have a *discussion* on Stack Overflow is in one of the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

**Do not ask a question seeking discussion on the main site**. All Stack Exchange sites are [intentionally designed to suppress discussion](http://blog.codinghorror.com/civilized-discourse-construction-kit/), in order to help focus people on *questions* and *answers*:

> Almost every design decision we made was informed by our desire to push discussion down, to inhibit it in every way we could. Spare us the long-winded diatribe, just *answer the damn question already*.

Therefore, any question seeking an opinion or discussion on the main site will be extremely unwelcome and not well-received.

On the other hand, the chat rooms were created for the purpose of discussion, so you might have better luck at starting one there.